# Are blood vessels organs?

Tags: terminology, blood-circulation

Are blood vessels classified as organs? Organs compose of 2 or more tissues and perform a certain function. Blood vessels have 3 different tissues and perform a function (transport blood), yet I do not see them being identified as an organ. Why is this? Are they organs? Or do they hold their own classification?

Comment: Did you copy the question from [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080703182004AA2NPRi)?

Comment: @Cornelius, no need to ask. That is a copy/paste.

Comment: @Cornelius - nice find. Wouldn't this issue be a nice one for Meta? It looks like rep mining to me? I retracted my upvote. I might be downvoting if OP doesn't respond.

Comment: @AliceD I believe similar issues were discussed on Meta.SE, but I can't find the question now. Anyway I consider we should focus on giving better answers than the ones on Yahoo, where, again, the best answer is a copy-paste from Wikipedia.

Comment: @AliceD btw,  ain't hematology a bad tag for this question? The question is not about blood pathology.

Comment: @Cornelius - It is a bad tag; I just added terminology and wavered to delete hematology. Thing is there has to be some tag linking it to the vascular system - what about blood-circulation? +1 for your answer btw

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256933/what-to-do-if-a-question-is-crossposted-from-a-non-stackexchange-website

Comment: Artery and veins are organs, but capillaries are not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cardiovascular system is usually lumped together as an organ. So blood vessels would be included here but you are right in that this is a bit strange being that it includes the heart and the vasculature.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if they are classified as organs, but basically, blood vessels match the criteria for being organs.

Quoting [SIU School of Medicine](http://www.siumed.edu/~dking2/crr/cvguide.htm#vessels):

> Blood vessels are basically tubular organs found within other organs.

[Biology Reference](http://www.biologyreference.com/Oc-Ph/Organ.html) states the same:

> Even the glands within the integument can be considered organs; any gland is primarily secretory epithelium surrounded by connective tissue for support and protection. Likewise, the **blood vessels** and nerves in these organs **are organs** unto themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes blood vessels can be called as [organs](http://www.studyread.com/organs-of-the-body). They are part of organ system. By definition an organ is one which is made of different tissues and contributes with other organs to a specific function in the body. Here blood vessels are made of different [tissues](http://www.studyread.com/types-of-tissues) like smooth muscle, epithelial tissue, elastic tissue etc.